# Using MONTH in If statement in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write an Excel macro that will look at the dates in column A and print each month listed in a column F. I am trying to use a for loop and If/Else statements but I can't seem to get it to work out correctly.

```
y = 2

Range("F2").Formula = "=MONTH(A3)"

For x = 4 To RowLast - 1
    If Range("A" & x).Month = Range("F" & y) Then
    Else
        y = y + 1
        Range("F" & y).Formula = "=MONTH(A" & x & ")"
    End If
Next
```

That is what I have thus far and it should print the first month found in Cell A3 to Cell F2 (which works), then go through every other date until it hits one line above the last. The if statements should check to make sure it's a new month and if it is print the month to the next cell in column F.

Please let me know if you have any questions. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RowLast = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

y = 2

Range("F2").Formula = "=MONTH(A3)"

For x = 4 To RowLast - 1
    Range("Z2").Formula = "=MONTH(A" & x & ")"
    If Range("Z2").Value = Range("F" & y).Value Then
    Else
        y = y + 1
        Range("F" & y).Formula = "=MONTH(A" & x & ")"
    End If
Next
```

Comment: can I combine it with a function to hide all the columns which have the Month(1) like  
Range("D:G").Formula = "=MONTH(1)"

Columns("D:BC").Select

If Columns("D:G").Hidden = True Then
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
Else
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
End If

Answer (score 0):

I think your if statement is causing the problems.  Do you even need an if statement here if you are just printing the month?

Comment: The problem is that there are multiple dates in Column A and several of them will have the same month but I only want it to show up in Column F once so that I can total another column based upon the month.

Comment: On the very first run through the loop you are checking that A4 = Y2 is that correct

Comment: You also might be checking the column F month before you have defined it.

Comment: I was trying to have it check only F column values that are there so initially F2 is found, then the for/if loop should be checking against F2 until F3 is created.

Comment: If you think the if statement is good and necessary you could try getting a property of the Range("F" & y) ... something like Range("F" & y).month or Range("F" & y).value

Comment: can you describe the behavior it is giving with the current code?

Comment: There is nothing added after the first part places 12 (for December) into F2. The code isn't failing or causing a bug but it's not doing anything else.

Comment: Where is RowLast defined and calculated?

Comment: At the beginning of the module, it's defined as RowLast = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

Comment: To test that the if statement is always evaluating as true which I think it is have it set Range("F" & y) to text of true.  If it is always true then we need to rethink the if statement.

Comment: As another debugging test I would have it print the value of RowLast and verify it is greater than 4

Comment: I figured it out, all I had to do was put the value for the month that is currently being checked into a cell off screen and then check against this in the if statement. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @user3709645 If your question has been answered you should accept an answer so others don't continue to try an solve this question.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your specific question: `Month(date)` is a function that returns an integer corresponding to the month of the date argument. So `Month(Now)` would return 3, for example.

`.Month` is not a property of the .`Range` object so your code would throw an error ("Object doesn't support this property or method"). The code below shows how to use the `Month()` function in the way you want.

However, your code poses a wider question. Are you using VBA merely to automate your formula writing? If you are, then all well and good. But is it possible that you are using worksheet functions when, actually, VBA would serve you better? Is there a reason, for example, that you would use VBA to identify target months only to write those target months to your worksheet by way of an Excel formula?

I mention it because quite a few posts recently have limited their scope to how to automate Excel functions (probably as a result of recording macros) whereas VBA can be more capable than their imagination might allow.

Anyhow, here are two very similar versions of the same task: the first that writes the formulae and the second that writes the months. I hope it'll provoke some thought as to which automation type suits your needs:

**Code to write the formulae:**

```
Public Sub FormulaGenerator()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim firstRow As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim dateRange As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim hitList As Collection
    Dim refMonth As Integer
    Dim thisMonth As Integer
    Dim r As Long
    Dim output() As Variant
    Dim item As Variant

    'Set these for your own task.
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    firstRow = 3
    lastRow = 20

    'Read the values cell by cell
    Set dateRange = ws.Range(ws.Cells(firstRow, "A"), ws.Cells(lastRow, "A"))
    Set hitList = New Collection
    For Each cell In dateRange.Cells
        item = cell.Month
        thisMonth = Month(cell.Value)
        If thisMonth <> refMonth Then
            'It's a new month so populate the collection with the cell address
            hitList.Add cell.Address(False, False)
            refMonth = thisMonth
        End If
    Next

    'Populate the output array values
    ReDim output(1 To hitList.Count, 1 To 1)
    r = 1
    For Each item In hitList
        output(r, 1) = "=MONTH(" & item & ")"
        r = r + 1
    Next

    'Write the output array starting at cell "F2"
    ws.Cells(2, "F").Resize(UBound(output, 1)).Formula = output
End Sub
```

**Code to write the months as integers:**

```
Public Sub OutputGenerator()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim firstRow As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim dates As Variant
    Dim hitList As Collection
    Dim refMonth As Integer
    Dim thisMonth As Integer
    Dim r As Long
    Dim output() As Integer
    Dim item As Variant

    'Set these for your own task.
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    firstRow = 3
    lastRow = 23

    'Read the dates into an array
    dates = ws.Range(ws.Cells(firstRow, "A"), ws.Cells(lastRow, "A")).Value

    'Loop through the array to acquire each new date
    Set hitList = New Collection
    For r = 1 To UBound(dates, 1)
        thisMonth = Month(dates(r, 1))
        If thisMonth <> refMonth Then
            'It's a new date so populate the collection with the month integer
            hitList.Add thisMonth
            refMonth = thisMonth
        End If
    Next

    'Populate the output array
    ReDim output(1 To hitList.Count, 1 To 1)
    r = 1
    For Each item In hitList
        output(r, 1) = item
        r = r + 1
    Next

    'Write the output array starting at cell "F2"
    ws.Cells(2, "F").Resize(UBound(output, 1)).Value = output
End Sub
```